# Frequently Visited Sites has disappeared from Safari. How to restore?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

At some point after the upgrade to iOS 15.x, the Frequently Visited Sites section in Safari disappeared.  When I tap on the address bar, I only get Shared with You, Privacy Report and Reading List.

I see other people [reporting](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253222110) it as well, but don't see any solutions.  I've upgraded to iOS 15.3 in hopes that it will be fixed, but it wasn't.

Others suggested going into Settings > Safari and [toggling](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-delete-frequently-visited-on-iphone-4767258) the "Frequently Visited Sites" feature.  However, I do not have that toggle in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping there's a better way, but the only way I restored mine was to just visit them again many times.

Comment: I go to the same sites pretty much every day.  The section itself has never reappeared.

Comment: Took at least a week before I got any of mine back.